# keras precision recall whith sparse categorical_crossentropy

Tags: keras, loss-function, precision-recall

Is it possible to calculate precision, recall, val_precesion, and val_recall with `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss function? In this post, [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49019383/keras-precision-and-recall-is-greater-than-1-multi-classification) the author suggested to use `categorical_crossentropy` but in my case, I need to use the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`